# Storing hashed information as VARBINARY on SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the PHP `PASSWORD_HASH();` and `MCRYPT_ENCRYPT();` *MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256* for password/string encryption.

Is it safe to store them as VARBINARY on SQL and what need to be the maximum length of the column? Also, what is the maximum?

Comment: Are you using *both* methods at once? Your ideas on security are indeed not that *trivial*.

Comment: There is no use to ask you, what's the use for encrypting a hash, I presume. Something "You 'd never know which of them failed"  would be answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, password_hash is for passwords, mcrypt_encrypt is for other strings. So no, I do not use them at once.

Comment: A hash function might return a value of a certain length – but in regard to an _encryption_ function asking for the maximum length to expect makes little sense, because that will obviously depend on the _data_ that gets encrypted.

Comment: Is there a maximum length of the VARBINARY? I cannot find it on the documentation.